# WinError 2 cannot find file: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\sacremoses.exe' -> 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\sacremoses.exe.deleteme'

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Dalle-pytorch, but at every try, the following error appears:

> [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: 'c:\python39\Scripts\sacremoses.exe' -> 'c:\python39\Scripts\sacremoses.exe.deleteme'.

Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: What exact steps/commands did you already run?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pip install sacremoses